# How to fix error is associated with right button of mouse in Flashdevelop?

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

```
Main.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_MOUSE_DOWN, test);
private function test(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("ASDASD");
}
```

It's not working and output:

*
:Error: Access of possibly undefined property RIGHT_MOUSE_DOWN through a reference with static type MouseEvent.
Access of possibly undefined property
RIGHT_MOUSE_UP through a reference with static type MouseEvent.             Main.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_MOUSE_DOWN, test);
­                                                           ^
Build halted with errors (mxmlc-cli).
Done(1)*

```
Main.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, test);
private function test(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("ASDASD");
}
```

It's working:

Comment: Is this a compile time error?

Answer (score 0):

as documented [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html) that constant only supported for

> Runtime Versions:     AIR 1.0,
>
> Flash Player 11.2,
>
> Flash Lite 4

and above.

did you import MouseEvent class in right place?

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
```

Comment: @NealDavis , you are right, but maybe some one with similar question directed here by searching some thing like this question title, which have to solve his problem with that section

Comment: @NealDavis I selected version Flash Player 11.2, but not always working like with other versions.

Comment: As i said, flash player 11.2 and above. If you find any obstacle with it, us a more recently version . Flash 11 is out of date

Comment: @NealDavis Before your answer version my Flash Player was 21, but error was almost always.

Comment: >did you import MouseEvent class in right place? yep

Comment: @Moshtein i test it with **Air 20** that constant does not depreacated. please try `trace(Capabilities.version)` on your flash player 21 and check its out put

Comment: @NealDavis Output: WIN 21,0,0,242

Comment: @Moshtein its not believable but! 2 options left, **(1)** test your chance with this `Main.addEventListener("rightMouseDown", test);` on flash 21 **(2)** try using an earlier flash player (22 or 23)

Comment: @NealDavis 
>"rightMouseDown"
Big thx! Now all working. Do you know why don't work "MouseEvent.RIGHT_MOUSE_DOWN"? Got any ideas?

Comment: @Moshtein you are welcome :), i searched for it.. but i don't find any bug report about flash 21 and this issue, i'll update my answer when I realized it